# jQuery select if multiple elements has the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

Example HTML:

```
<div class="elem-1"></div>
<div class="elem-2"></div>
<div class="elem-2"></div>
<div class="elem-3"></div>
<div class="elem-4"></div>
<div class="elem-4"></div>
<div class="elem-4"></div>
```

Needed:
How can I select the div's which has "elem-2"s and "elem-4"s with jQuery selectors? (multiple elements has same class)

Comment: Are you looking to select only elements which share a class with another element?

Comment: Seems like I hit the language barrier again. The provided scenerio is only an example. I'm interested in doing that programmatically. I'm trying again: Let's say we have a div which have many child div's. Each child's class name is different but some child's class name is identical. I want to get the "identical" groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selector` will be given the value that you desire

http://jsfiddle.net/mMEN5/1

```
var selector = $();

var list = $('[class]').toArray().reduce(function(p, e){
    p = p || {};
    var classes = $(e).prop('class').split(/\s/);
    $.each(classes, function(i,c){
        p[c] = p[c] || [];
        p[c].push(e);
    });
    return p;
}, {})

for (el in list) if (list[el].length > 1) selector=selector.add(list[el]);
​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `,` to separate different selectors:

```
$(".elem-2, .elem-4")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.elem-2, .elem-4').hide() // or any other jquery method
```

By the way, it's not a `jQuery` selector, it's just a `CSS` selector, see [this article](http://webdesign.about.com/od/cssselectors/f/comma-in-css-selectors.htm) for an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have asked for css selector, we can also use the attributeStartsWith selector

I will just mention the selector usage. you can use to for any internal DOM chnage

alert($('div[class^="elem-2"], div[class^="elem-4"]').length);

here i have used .length just to give a correct count. Use can use above with id attributes also.